# Flat torsion-free connections

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, connections, gauge-theory

Can a manifold admit two different flat torsion-free connections? By different, I mean that there is not any diffeomorphism that makes the two equal. The question arises from me trying to explain to myself and to others an intuitive way to see two different flat connections over the same manifolds. The first attempt would be to find two non-isometric flat metrics over the same manifold that induce two different connections, but it looks to me like it is not possible.

Comment: Sorry you are right I was not clear that different meant non isometric

Comment: Well, then the  flat tori you get from different lattices in the plane are easily arranged to have different area, so they are not isometric.

Comment: @Mariano yeah flat tori were the example I was thinking of but it looked to me that all flat metrics induce the same connection: they both induce the same horizontal spaces or parallel transport... Am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah, I do want the connections to be different (in the sense that I specified). I do not really care about the metrics, I brought them up just as a way to get torsion-free connections.

Comment: Hint: If flat connections have nonconjugate  holonomy groups, then they cannot be isomorphic. You can find such already in the case of 2-dimensional torus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Levi-Civita connection on a flat torus is flat and torsion-free as was remarked in the comments. There are other ways to define torsion-free and flat connections. Such a connection is equivalent to an affine structure, that is, an atlas whose charts are related by affine transformations.

Consider an affine torus defined by taking the quotient of the plane minus the origin $ \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ by the group of dilations generated by $ x \mapsto 2x $. The natural linear connection on this is not equivalent to one given by a flat metric. For instance, the constructed affine torus is not geodesically complete.

I'm pretty certain that you could find two distinct connections that are both complete but can't think of an easy one right now.

Comment: Could you by chance expand more on what the "natural linear connection" is? If you have references for quotients of manifold with connections I would be happy to learn more about them

Comment: A map $ f: M \rightarrow M $ of a manifold with a linear connection $ \nabla$ is said to preserve the connection if $ \nabla_{f_\ast X } f_\ast Y = f_\ast \nabla_X Y$ for any vector fields $ X$ and $Y$. Equivalently, the differential $ f_\ast: TM \rightarrow TM$ preserves the horizontal distribution. If there is a group of $\nabla$ preserving diffeomorphisms acting freely on $M$, a natural connection is induced on the quotient manifold.

Comment: The connection being given by $ \nabla'_{[X]} [Y] = [ \nabla_X Y]$, where $ [ \cdot]$ denotes the equivalence class of a vector. 
I don't really have a reference on putting connections on a quotient manifold. The most natural examples are of course symmetric spaces and coset spaces. 
The specific structure you're looking for( a manifold with a flat torsion free connection) is called an affine structure. 'Geometric Sructures on Manifolds' by Goldman is a reference, one disadvantage of it is that it contains a bit too much. But you could look at the sections on affine manifolds if you'd like.